# Wordpress SSL Redirection with One Sub-Folder Exception

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

Sorry to ask such a total newbie question - I'm struggling with an exception to our SSL redirection rules on our Wordpress site. Basically, everything is redirecting as http to https.

Feedburner doesn't support https feeds (grr!) so I'm hoping to create an exception to prevent requests for `http://domain.co.uk/feed/` being redirected to `https://domain.co.uk/feed/`

Our redirect rules in .htaccess look a little like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Any and all help really, really appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
#exclude /feed/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/feed/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#This section is optional
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#send any cached https /feed/ back to http
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/feed/ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you previously visited the `/feed/` URL and were redirected, this redirect will be cached in your browser. To test that it works correctly after changing the rule, change to private browsing, or clear you browser cache.

If you think that existing clients have the same problem i.e. a cached https redirect to `/feed/` you can include the optional section to send them back to http

Comment: Hi Ulrich, thanks so much for replying! Your solution *should* work - for a reason I don't understand, requests to http://domain.co.uk/feed/ redirect to the secure version of https:domain.co.uk/ I've pastebinned the full htaccess, but obviously I don't expect your to work through it if you don't have time http://pastebin.com/dVgfnuew

Comment: @RichardBaxter Your htaccess file looks ok. Make sure that you are testing in private browsing mode to ensure that you do not have any cached 301 redirects